# Retrieving new entries from a database since last update

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have created a webpage which is designed to ping my databse every 5 seconds for new changes but at the moment my method is buggy, sometimes new entries are doubled up and sometimes they don't appear at all, how am I best to go around this.

I've got this Jquery snippet for AJAX requests to the php script which checks the databse. I use javascript to get the time and use a function to change the timezone around.

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
       var last = new Date().addHours(10).toMysqlFormat();
        function new(){
           var url = 'new.php?l=' + last;
            $('#new').append($('<div>').load(url));
            last = new Date().addHours(10).toMysqlFormat();
            //console.log("Updated:" + last + ".");
        }
        setInterval(function(){new()}, 5000);


    });
```

I send to that script the last time it was checked for updates.

This PHP script is as follows:

```
if (isset($_GET["l"])){
    $dmin = $_GET["l"];
    $dmax = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

       $sql = "SELECT `ID`,`Name`  FROM `foo` WHERE (`datetime` BETWEEN   '".$dmin ."' AND  '".$dmax ."') ";
```

After I query the sql statement I loop through the results and return it to the javascripts, where in my process can these errors be coming from or is there a better way to do this?

*I think that one of the problems is that my PHP time is 1 or 2 seconds different from the javascript time as for a test, I changed my date back 5 seconds and I got a duplicate of everything. I need a way of using the updates so that the page can be loaded for months and not lose track*

Comment: you can pass record id instead

Comment: What do you mean by that? I need to update all new orders in the database since the last update, do you mean pass the last id? What do I do when I first load the page, what id do I go off, or do I retrieve the last ID?

Comment: yes, you store last id of record you have on your page and pass it instead of time, then select all new records that have higher id then the last id, and updated last id on your page. on first load you can just use 0 as last id and it will load all records for you

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "SELECT `ID`,`Name`  FROM `foo` ORDER BY `id` DESC
```

Use these query to get the latest entries

Comment: if u have autoincrement field in table, u can easily find the latest entries

Comment: I do have an autoincrement field but don't know to check if the id was already loaded before...

Comment: Yeah it is unique, what my problem is, is that I only want to retrieve each new record once, your method retrieves every value

Comment: `$sql = "SELECT ID,Name  FROM foo ORDER BY id DESC Limit 10`

Comment: u can use some limt values to get the latest entries.. if u use limit 5 last 5 entries only displayed